# Quarkus. How to mock method inside the method

Tags: java, testing, mockito, quarkus

The question is how to mock the method inside another method in the class.
For example I have service:

```
@Getter
@ApplicationScoped
public class Service{
  public byte[] sendRequest(Integer id, String name){
    try {
      return get(id, name);
    } catch (Exteption exception) {
      throw new MyException("Error during get data " + exception.getMEssage());
    }  
  }

  public byte[] get(Integer id, String name){
    ...some code...
  }
}
```

and test class

```
@QuakrusTest
public class ServiceTest{
  
  @InjectMock
  Service service;

  @Test
  void test(){
    when(service.get(anyInt(), anyString())).thenThrow(new RuntimeException("MyError");
    MyException myExpection = assertThrows(MyException .class, () -> service.sendRequest(1, "name"));
    assertEquals("Error during get data MyError", myExpection.getMessage());
  }
}
```

So I need to mock the *get()* method to throw an expection to check if it is caught by my try/catch-block inside `sendRequest` and that the message of MyException is correct.
But my main problem is that *when(service.get(anyString())* doesn't work.

The ressult is

> Expected MyException to be thrown but nothing was thrown.

Comment: this call `when(service.get(anyString())` is missing the `anyInt()` parameters

Comment: Yes. Changed. Just typo when created post

Comment: It should complain that you can't use `when()` on your service because that's not a mock in the first place, and shouldn't be because that's your subject under test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mock, which you are using for your service, overwrites per default all methods with an empty method body and returns a default value e.g. `null`. So the mock of your *get()*  method works, but your *sendRequest* method never calls it, as it is overwritten by an empty method. So this is what happens when you call `sendRequest` on your mock.

What you can do to fix this is to configure the mock to call the actual implementation of your class:

```
when(service.sendRequest(1, "name")).thenCallRealMethod()
```